# Android: writing AudioTrack to .wav file - possible?

Tags: android, audio

So I need to generate some tones with `ToneGenerator` and write them to .wav file. Is is possible using `ToneGenerator` or `AudioTrack`?

Are there any ways to access audio frames directly in AudioTrack, record to file with AudioOutput or do anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

```
public class GenerateAndPlaySound extends Activity {
    private final int duration = 3; // seconds
    private final int sampleRate = 8000;
    private final int numSamples = duration * sampleRate;
    private final double sample[] = new double[numSamples];
    private final double freqOfTone = 440; // hz

    private final byte generatedSnd[] = new byte[2 * numSamples];

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Use a new tread as this can take a while
        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                genTone();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        playSound();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    void genTone(){
        // fill out the array
        for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
            sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate/freqOfTone));
        }

        // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
        // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
        int idx = 0;
        for (final double dVal : sample) {
            // scale to maximum amplitude
            final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
            // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);

        }
    }

    void playSound(){
        final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
        audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
        audioTrack.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is not a direct answer, but is a viable solution.

Comment: @kagali-san I understood that you are asking for the technique of writing the output of 'ToneGenerator' to a .wav file. This code is only creating a 440Hz sine wave and playing it via audioTrack. So, no 'ToneGenerator', no wav save. Hmm

Comment: this doesn't answer the original question. This snippet generates the tone but it takes few seconds to do it and the lag is too much for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

[ToneGenerator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html) specifies the output stream type, to which the generated audio data is written. There is no possibility to directly access the generated audio data.

Of course, you can record the played tones, e.g. via internal microphone. But that's probably not what you wanted.

You could also record them digitally on some devices by using [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) when using the appropriate settings for audioSource, sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat and streamType.

Concerning AudioTrack, since you have to use write() methods, you necessarily have direct access to the audio data.